# How to get each value of gradient?

Tags: css, gradient

How to get each value of gradient css such as color , color location and gradient type using jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradients are set using the **background** property in CSS (not background-color).  This is because gradients are actually a special type of image.  So, to use jQuery to get gradient values, you would use:

```
$(selector).css('background');
```